# How to Pass foreach loop variable to URL decoder in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am getting a hashmap from server named as list and I'm iterating through it. I want to encode they key value of list and assign it href of `<a>`. So how can I achieve this?

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="report" begin="0">
    <tr><td><a href=<%= URLEncoder.encode("what should i put here to encode report.key") %>>${report.key}</a></td>
    <td>${report.value}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do this in 2 ways.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="report" begin="0">
<tr><td><a href=<%= URLEncoder.encode(pageContext.getAttribute("report")) %> >${report.key}</a></td>
<td>${report.value}</td></tr>
```

OR

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="report">
    <c:url value="name" var="report"/>
    <tr>
       <td><a href="${name}">${report.key}</a></td>
       <td>${report.value}</td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```